# How to allocate a global int* dynamically?

Tags: c++, global-variables, mergesort, multiple-definition-error

I'm trying to do a Merge Sort code in C++, and to avoid a lot of memory use, I want to declare the auxiliary vector as a global variable. As you might know, using the global variable strategy the space used is **O(1)**, while using the other one, it's **O(N logN)**.
But there's a small problem, I don't know the size of the vectors that will be used to test my code, so I need that global variable to be dynamically allocated.

I've already tried to do something like that:

This is from the .h archive:

```
void mymergesort_recursive(std::vector<int> &v, SortStats &stats, int i = 0, 
                           int f = 0, bool nouveau = true);
int *aux = nullptr;
```

This is from the .cpp archive:

```
void mymergesort_recursive(std::vector<int> &v, SortStats &stats, int i, 
                           int f, bool nouveau) {
    if (nouveau) {
        stats.recursive_calls = 1;
        f = int(v.size());
        // Allocates the variable aux according with the vector size. This makes a lot of memory economy.

        aux = new int[f];
    } else {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Actually, I've tried this too:

```
aux = (int *)malloc(f * sizeof(int));
```

```
aux = static cast <int*>(malloc(f * sizeof(int)));
```

And other try and error possibilities that had all resulted on the same error :-(

> multiple definition of `aux'

I have looked for some other questions in this forum here, but despite there's a lot of similar questions, I wasn't able to extract a solution to  exactly this problem.

I think have explained the problem clearly, but if there's something obscure, please, ask.

Comment: You don't. Using global variables is an even worse idea than using raw pointers an manual dynamic memory management.

Comment: The error doesn't come from the line you posted.

Comment: @tkausl in the error line is: 
" CMakeFiles/labSorttests.dir/src/mymergesort.cpp.o:/home/mypc/Desktop/Lab3/labsort190322_1014/src/mysortfunctions.h:38: multiple definition of `aux'   "

In the line 38 of this file, the .h, this is what is written:

int* aux = nullptr;

Comment: Typical merge sort space overhead is O(n). Top down uses O(log(n)) stack space, but this doesn't affect the overall space complexity of O(n). As mentioned below, merge sort can use ⌈n/2⌉ space, but it's a bit slower. [Block merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_sort) is stable, takes O(1) space, but it's about 50% slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you're declaring a variable on the header.

On the header you should put

```
extern int* aux;
```

And then in some .cpp you should put:

```
int* aux= nullptr;
```

Anyway, you should seriously consider instead of `int* aux` use `std::vector<int> aux;`.

- It will keep the count of elements for you
- It will not use almost any space when empty.
- It will grow as needed.
- You can `reserve` memory before you use it to optimize it.
- You will not need to call `delete`/`free`

Comment: And yes, as someone noted, using a global variable is a bad idea in general.

Answer (score 0):

Using a global auxiliary vector will not achieve **O(1)** memory space overhead, the size of the vector will be that of the largest vector you try to sort (or at least half that with a clever implementation), hence **O(N)** space overhead.

Furthermore, using a global variable makes the code non reentrant, non thread safe, and keeps the overhead after the sort is done.

Here is a better approach:

- write a recursive `mergesort_helper` function that takes this temporary array to store the left subarray during the merge phase.
- n the `mergesort` function, allocate a temporary array of size `(N + 1) / 2` elements and pass it to the recursive `mergesort_helper` function.
- free the temporary array
- return to the caller.